# How to find symmetric difference between files in HDFS?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have 2 files in hdfs: /my/path/in/hdfs/part-r-* (about 1000 parts, ~10000 rows each) and /my/another/path/in/hdfs/part-r-* (same sizes). The first file contains data in following form:

```
id1 111
id6 212
id3 984
```

and so on.
The second one is like:

```
999 id8
15 id4
93 id1
```

I want to find all the id's in the first file that does not appear in the second file and vice versa. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: You need result like this maube ??? : (id6 212; id3 984; id8 999; id4 15)

Comment: I'd suggest looking into Spark - read the dirs into two datasets and then join them to identify unmatched rows. There's almost no reason to use MapReduce in 2021... Or you can put external Hive tables over both directories and join that way if you have Hive installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I doubt that this kind of computations is fit for the strict paradigm of MapReduce purely based at how complicated and calculation-heavy that procedure can be (even though you said that the two files for input in your case are the same size), so I thought this would be a good case to find ways to cut corners while keeping things simple.

First things first, to get rid of extra IO fat, you might want to put those two files into a single directory (let's say `\input` here for the sake of simplicity) just to bypass the multiple input kerfuffle. After that, things can be much more easier to do with just one MapReduce job.

In the Map phase, all you need to do is set the IDs from both files as keys and set the "filenames" of their occurrences as their value (this is a safe way to find the symmetric difference while keeping on generalizing that maybe an ID can be seen multiple times within a file). Those "filenames" don't really need to be actual filenames, you can just put Strings of `A` and `B` to indicate that this particular ID in this particular line was found withing the first or second file respectively.

In the Reduce phase, you can put all the values that refer to a single key/ID in a `HashSet` collection which holds all the **unique** values you put into it. This means that for each reducer (aka each ID), a `HashSet` is created to put several instances of `A` and `B` Strings, only to store just *one* of those instances. So:

- an ID that is seen in just the first file will have a `HashSet` collection with  just `A` in it,
- an ID that is seen in just the second file will have a `HashSet` collection with  just `B` in it,
- an ID that is seen in both files will have a `HashSet` collection with `A` and `B` in it (aka the **intersection** of the files, which you *DON'T* need).

With that, you can simple check every ID's `HashSet` and write only those of the first two options as described above.

This type of job can look like this (the Reduce function here doesn't really need to have a value in the key-value pairs, so I just put an empty `String` to make things more simple):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class SymDiff 
{
    /* input:  <byte_offset, line_of_dataset>
     * output: <ID, file>
     */
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> 
    {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            String[] line = value.toString().split(" ");    // split each line to two columns
            
            // if the first column consists of integers, put the ID from the 2nd column as the key
            // and set "B" as the value to imply that the particular ID was found on the second file
            // else, put the ID from the first column as the key
            // and set "A" as the value to imply that the particular ID was found on the first file
            if(line[0].matches("\\d+"))     // (lazy way to see if the first string is an int without throwing an exception)
                context.write(new Text(line[1]), new Text("B"));
            else
                context.write(new Text(line[0]), new Text("A"));
        }
    }

    /* input: <ID, file>
     * output: <ID, "">
     */
    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
    {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            HashSet<String> list_of_files = new HashSet<String>();

            // store all the instances of "A" and "B" for each ID in a HashSet with unique values
            for(Text value : values)
                list_of_files.add(value.toString());
            
            // only write the IDs which they values only contain "A" or "B" (and not both) on their set 
            if(list_of_files.contains("A") && !list_of_files.contains("B") || (!list_of_files.contains("A") && list_of_files.contains("B")))
                context.write(key, new Text(""));
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // set the paths of the input and output directories in the HDFS
        Path input_dir = new Path("input");
        Path output_dir = new Path("output");

        // in case the output directory already exists, delete it
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        if(fs.exists(output_dir))
            fs.delete(output_dir, true);

        // configure the MapReduce job
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Symmetric Difference");
        job.setJarByClass(SymDiff.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);    
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, input_dir);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output_dir);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

You can see the desired output in the screenshot below:

[image]